# not secure in another pc but in my aws rdp is installed

Tags: amazon-ec2, xampp

Here the problem I'm get aws windows server 2019 and install xampp for easy use and tried to install ssl and virtual host 443 and he install i follow so many way to install ssl but in my own browser is not secure suddenly open rdp and install chrome want see he secure how in rdp secure outside not working

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to windows Server through any linux instance (such as your NAT Instance in public subnet) in same VPC by SSH tunnel.

Comment: thanks. but how can make it

Comment: if i miss with the way i said the question my question about ssl secure not about log to instance

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).